# Make Lua table nil via a function

Tags: lua, lua-table

I create an empty table, t. I then try to set it nil by using function destroy. While in function, the table becomes nil, but outside of the function nothing has happened to it until I explicitly set it to nil

Is there any way to set a table to nil via using a function in Lua?

```
local t = {}

local function destroy(input)
    print("in function",input)
    input = nil
    print("in function",input)
end

print(t)
destroy(t)
print(t)
t = nil
print(t)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as "setting a table to `nil`". You can set one of the values *within* a table to `nil`. You can set a *variable* to `nil`. But you cannot set a table to `nil`. Just like you cannot set an integer to `nil` or set a string to `nil`.

The only way to set a *variable* is to actually set that variable. `input` and `t` are two separate variables. They may both be holding the same table, but modifications to one variable will not magically affect the other variable.

If you want `destroy` to be able to generally change the place where the caller of `destroy` stored the table being passed in... you can't. A function generally cannot affect the variables used to *call it*. A function's parameters contain the values taken from the arguments passed to it; they do not contain the *variables themselves*, if for no other reason than the fact that you don't have to pass variables to a function (you can pass the result of expressions and so forth, which don't have to be stored in "variables").

There are specific instances where a function might be able to do that. In your very specific code, because `local t` is visible to the `destroy` function, it can actually perform `t = nil`. However, that only works in this specific code; move `t`'s declaration below `destroy`, and now it can't reach it.

Overall, what you want cannot be done.

Comment: A function argument is a value derived from an expression. It is only happenstance if an expression is simply a variable.